Is it an issue if I slightly alter a check just so that it will scan for Mobile Deposit?
Got a check from someone who lives in another state. I am trying to deposit it through my mobile app, but it won't go through.  My bank is online only and the bank that the check is written from is a regional bank that doesn't have a branch anywhere near me.  The problem is that the person who wrote the check went below the line when writing in the memo field and the tail of of the letters crosses into the routing number of the bank, which is preventing the app from being able to recognize it.
Would it be illegal and/or void out the check if I used a little white out to get rid of the tail of the letter?


Would it be illegal and/or void out the check if I used a little white out to get rid of the tail of the letter?

Not a lawyer, but a check is essentially a "contract" between the two parties. Altering the contract without the permission of both parties could void the contract.
However, one could argue that altering the check to make the routing number more visible (provided you don't actually change the routing number) is not materially modifying the terms of the contract, just clarifying the information. Certainly modifying the payee or amount would be material and would be more serious.
So technically a bank could refuse to process the check because of an alteration (since they would be liable if they knowingly processed an altered check), and the other party could try to void the check because it was altered.
If the bank accepts it and the other party does not refute it, you are probably okay. The safest route would be to notify the other party and get approval for the alteration, or have them write a new check.
Another option would be to take the check to a different local bank and see if they will give you a cashier's check or money order for you to deposit in your bank, but I would not be surprised if banks were suspicious and did not want to do that (e.g. if it was fraudulent they would have a hard time getting the money back from you).
